# Dos command to delete files of a folder to recycle bin

Tags: windows, command-line

```
del /q "C:\Users\John Cena\Desktop\YT\*"
```

I am creating a batch file. The above command permanently deletes all the files of a particular folder. But I don't want to delete the files permanently. I am looking for an alternative of "del" command which will help me to delete the files to recycle bin so that if I need any deleted file I can restore that from recycle bin.

Comment: Normally a batch file should know that files can be permanently deleted.  Try solution 2 in the article below to move to recycle bin:  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/520260/howplustoplusremoveplusfilesplustoplusrecyleplusbi

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using the `del` command.

You could use PowerShell for that.

You need first to start the PowerShell command prompt as Administrator and run
the following:

```
Install-Module -Name Recycle
```

From now on you may include the following line in any batch file, without the
need to run as Administrator:

```
powershell "Remove-ItemSafely 'C:\Users\John Cena\Desktop\YT\*'" -Force
```

The parameter `-Force` is to avoid the prompt for permission to delete.

Comment: The user who will run the batch file will not have administrative privilege.

Comment: Admin permissions are only required once during the installation of the Recycle module. Its subsequent usage does not require any special permissions.